# why is my else statement ignored in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my if statement else (no records) is completely ignored if I try to wrap it in an if statement like

```
<% if (@genre) == ('2') %>  and <% end %>
```

can't figure out why it is ignoring the else statement

This works fine

```
<% if (@assessment).present?  && (@q1a).present? && (@q2a).present? && (@q3a).present? && (@q3a).present? && (@q4a).present? && (@q5a).present? && (@q6a).present? && (@q7a).present? && (@q8a).present? && (@q9a).present? && (@q10a).present? && (@q11a).present? && (@q12a).present? && (@q13a).present? && (@q14a).present? && (@q15a).present? %>
     completed                        
<% elsif (@assessment).present? %>
    in progress 
<% end %>                                                                   
<% else %>
    no records                         
<% end %>
```

[image: this is what the end result I want to be]

This ignores else

```
<% if (@genre) == ('2') %>

<% if (@assessment).present?  && (@q1a).present? && (@q2a).present? && (@q3a).present? && (@q3a).present? && (@q4a).present? && (@q5a).present? && (@q6a).present? && (@q7a).present? && (@q8a).present? && (@q9a).present? && (@q10a).present? && (@q11a).present? && (@q12a).present? && (@q13a).present? && (@q14a).present? && (@q15a).present? %>
     completed                        
<% elsif (@assessment).present? %>
   in progress 
<% end %>                                                                   
<% else %>
   no records                         
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

[image]

I tried to remove the <% end %> after the elsif and before the <% else %> I get a syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

Also tried

```
<% if (@genre) == ('2') %>
<% if (@assessment).present?  && (@q1a).present? && (@q2a).present? && (@q3a).present? && (@q3a).present? && (@q4a).present? && (@q5a).present? && (@q6a).present? && (@q7a).present? && (@q8a).present? && (@q9a).present? && (@q10a).present? && (@q11a).present? && (@q12a).present? && (@q13a).present? && (@q14a).present? && (@q15a).present? %>
     completed                        
<% elsif (@assessment).present? %>
      in progress 
<% elsif (@assessment).blank? %>
       no records                         
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your first example that is "working fine" cannot actually be working.  It is syntactically incorrect and will throw an exception.  You have an orphaned else block there.  The second example has one to many `end` statements and would also throw an exception. Same deal with your last example.  If I were you, I'd clean up the unnecessary parentheses, and fix your indentations.  The solution will likely pop out at you once the code is cleaned up a bit.

Comment: You don't need all those parentheses, `if @genre == '2'` or `if(@genre == '2')` are fine as are `elsif @assessment.present?` or `elsif(@assessment.present?)`. And that second conditional would probably be better structured as an `@array_of_qNa.all?(&:present?)` or something like that, 15 instance variables seems a little excessive and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your `if` too soon.

Change:

```
<% end %>                                                                   
<% else %>
```

to just:

```
<% else %>
```

Comment: When I try to remove the <% end %> the <% else %> is skipped
                      
<% elsif (@assessment).present? %>
    in progress  
<% else %>
     no records                         
<% end %>
<% end %>